# Custom Loop through category menu to include sub categories

Tags: php, categories, loop, menus

In my custom wordpress theme I currently have the below loop to the main categories

```
<?php
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object('navigation');
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
foreach($items as $item)
{
?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $item->url ?>"><?php echo $item->title ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

So it'll just list out each like so:

- Cat A
- Cat B
- Cat C
- Cat D

But I have now added some subcategories under `Cat B` so I would like to have it as so:

- Cat A
- Cat B

  - Cat B 1
  - Cat B 2
- Cat C
- Cat D

I know what to do regarding the html markup but what php command do I use in the loop to distinguish the subcategories?

Comment: If this is a nav menu, why not just use [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and let it handle the hierarchical output for you?

Comment: Correct, sorry new to wordpress, had a custom loop as i thought i could customise it easier (moving existing site into wordpress) but can see you can pass arguments into it which means i can use it